# How to speed up connection between R scripts and Shiny app on remote server

Tags: r, server, shiny, connection

I have a Shiny server configured through Ubuntu 16 on Digital Ocean droplet. Also, have an Shiny app under /srv/shiny-server.

The app downloads stock prices from Yahoo Finance, calculates different metrics in several xts and data frame objects and plots them.

Currently, it downloads and manipulates prices of only 4 stocks, but already takes 12-15 seconds to load fully.

So, in order to speed it up, I decided to divide it to 2 R scripts and 1 Shiny app. First script (A) to download and save the prices from Yahoo, afterwards second script (B) to calculate and save the metrics, and lastly the Shiny app (C) to plot them reactively.

The most time consuming processes are A and B. The idea is that A and B will be executed only once per day and C will be called by users many times.

I managed to connect the executions of A, B and C in RStudio on my local machine using source(A) at the beginning of script B and source(B) at the beginning of C. It decreased the full loading time to 4-6 seconds.

However, when I try to repeat that connection method on my remote server it again loads for 12-15 seconds. A, B and C are located under /srv/shiny-server.

I tried to apply different connection method using save.image() instead of source(), but attach(".RData") in C does not recognise the data from save.image() in B. May be because different server powers the remote host every time the app is called and that server does not find the data from attach(".RData").

Thanks in advance for any help on how to speed up the connection between A, B and C on my remote server and decrease the app loading time.

Comment: As you mentioned, script A and B only run once per day. I think you can set up a CRON job to run script A and B once per day and save the results as `.rds` or `.RData` file. Your shiny app can read directly from the stored files.

Comment: OK, but the point is how to make the app (C) to read directly the. RData file from B. It does not find it currently using load(". RData") or attach(". RData"). May be I have to save A and B in different directory on my remote server and/or to specify the exact path of the .RData file when calling attach()?

Comment: Read using either relative or absolute path, you can google it.